# How to check if Variant is empty and assign other variable to it in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a function that has 3 inputs, were two of them are optional: `colOffsetA` & `colOffsetB`. If only one of the two optional ones is used in the function, then I wish that this value is automatically assigned to the empty one as well. Right now the code assigns the value 0 for `colOffsetB` for some reason.

```
Function TestCode(cellA As Range, Optional colOffsetA As Variant, Optional colOffsetB As Variant) As String

    If IsEmpty(colOffsetB) Then
        colOffsetB = colOffsetA
    End If
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe what your looking for is `IsMissing` instead of `IsEmpty`.  Try this:

```
If IsMissing(colOffsetB) = True Then
    colOffsetB = colOffsetA
End If
```

Here is a [great article](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optionalargumentstoprocedures.aspx) on Optional arguments.

Answer (score 1):

using vbNUllString is little more speedy than IsEmpty, x="",....

```
Function TestCode(cellA As Range, Optional colOffsetA As Variant, Optional colOffsetB As Variant) As String
If colOffsetB=vbNullString Then colOffsetB = colOffsetA
do
end function
```

if your condition is basic put all on the some row and `end if` is not necessary.
hope you have help

Answer (score 0):

How if used like this?

```
dim Var as variant ' Declare here without parenthesis
if isempty(var) then
    redim var(0)
    else
    redim preserve var(ubound(var)+1)
end if
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.